# How can I join two links to resemble tabs?

Tags: html, css, user-interface, tabs, navigation

I would like to create style that represents two tabs - when you click on each tab it's a href link. The following is my feeble attempt. So the first (active) tab is the 'Owners' tab where the tab has a white background, the second tab has a grey background.

I want to change it in two ways:

1. I want the border black line to extend to the end of the page (at the moment the line just stops at the end of the Pets tab)
2. I want the non-active tab (the second tab in this example) to have a small white border around the grey

```css
.active-tab {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  padding: 14px 25px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: underline;
  display: inline-block;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.inactive-tab {
  background-color: #B8B8B8;
  color: black;
  padding: 14px 25px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: underline;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<a class="active-tab" href="default.asp" target="_blank">Owners</a><a class="inactive-tab" href="default.asp" target="_blank">Pets</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've adjusted your fiddle with the changes you requested, and explanations on why the changes were made.

https://jsfiddle.net/6whgpqv0/

```css
nav {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black; /* A line all the way to the end */
  display: flex; /* Justify all content to the start of the container */
}

nav a {
  display: inline-block; /* Make the link inline blocks so that it will adhere to the negative margin rule */
  margin-bottom: -1px; /* Offset the bottom of the link by 1px so the bottom border overlaps with the nav border */
}

.active-tab {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  padding: 14px 25px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: underline;
  display: inline-block;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.inactive-tab {
  background-color: #B8B8B8;
  color: black;
  padding: 14px 25px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: underline;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #fff; /* White border around the inactive tab */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I hope this is the result you want

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <style>
        .active-tab {
            background-color: white;
            color: black;
            padding: 14px 25px;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: underline;
            display: inline-block;
            border-top: 1px solid black;
            border-left: 1px solid black;
            border-right: 1px solid black;
        }

        .inactive-tab {
            background-color: #B8B8B8;
            color: black;
            padding: 14px 25px;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: underline;
            display: inline-block;
            border: 2px solid white;
        }

        .line {
            border-bottom:1px solid black;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <a class="active-tab" href="default.asp" target="_blank">Owners</a><a class="inactive-tab" href="default.asp"
        target="_blank">Pets</a>

    <div class="line">

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

If you still need help, comment here and I will try to help you

Comment: Thanks Anne, that's almost it! I dont want the bottom line on the active tab; I also want the black line to connect (i.e. no gaps)

Answer (score 1):

I added a wrapper `div` around your `a`s to extend the black border to the end of the page. I also added a `1px solid white` border to `.inactive-tab`. Update example:

```css
.tabs {
  display: flex;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.tabs a {
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}

.active-tab {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  padding: 14px 25px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: underline;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

.inactive-tab {
  background-color: #B8B8B8;
  color: black;
  padding: 14px 25px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: underline;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
<a class="active-tab" href="default.asp" target="_blank">Owners</a>
<a class="inactive-tab" href="default.asp" target="_blank">Pets</a>
</div>
```

Comment: thats very close... just need a white border at the bottom of pets